# Send SMS using Twilio in React-Native

Tags: react-native, sms, twilio, send

I have been researching for many days on how to send sms using Twilio in React-Native. I haven't found a single example that works! I thought this should be simple but apparently not.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

While not ReactNative, I wrote a post about [how to send SMS messages in React](https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-an-sms-react-twilio). The idea for ReactNative will be the same though. You don't want to make requests to the Twilio API directly from your application, you'd need to store your credentials in the app somehow and a malicious user could decompile it and abuse your account.

Instead you want to build a server application that sends the messages and make requests to that from your ReactNative application.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I have seen you commenting in other questions by sharing your project in React but you have to know these are not the same technologies. BMX has stated that he is using React-Native which is not the same as React.

Comment: That may be the case, but the principle is the same. You need to build a server application that can make calls to the Twilio API and keep your API credentials safe and then make requests to that application from your client side (ReactNative in this case) application.

Comment: how would you do that using for ex. AWS lambda?

Comment: @BurimSyla That would depend on a whole bunch of things that aren't supplied as part of the question. Is that something you're asking now? It would likely be better for you to submit that as a full question rather than spending time in the comments of another question.

Comment: I actually cannot submit a question that's why I am asking here, is it possible to start a chat conversation to discuss it there?

Comment: I’m out at events this week, but you can email me at philnash@twilio.com and I can try to help you out.